# Books to study quantum thermodynamics and quantum decoherence

Tags: decoherence, quantum-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations)

My friend is having a hard time finding books to self-study quantum thermodynamics and quantum decoherence.
(search on amaxon would bring almost no book... so what books should he choose?)

Comment: I've linked you to the book recommendation thread as there are a few questions there listing books for thermodynamics and quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

go to the below link my friend you can so many

http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Quantum_Thermodynamics.html?id=NaCjwZCnI_gC&redir_esc=y